# FusionCharts integration from source page to multiple unreliable ones

Tags: php, mysql, api, fusioncharts

I have the source site that contains polls, charts and a button which displays HTML code.
This code can be used to integrate those charts in multiple websites, without necessarily trusting our DB and server credentials to the authors of these websites.

The question is : How could I integrate the charts (which are a FusionCharts implementation) from the first site to the second or a third/fourth/fifth ones, protecting my stuff at the same time?

I have no idea how this can be implemented, since anyone can embed these charts in their websites.

Any thoughts to help me unstuck would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about serving your data as JSON URL and then restrict which referrers can access this?

Comment: The thing is that anyone could embed that code into their website.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about protecting your js code, you could try to obfuscate it by using [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) or [jScrambler](https://jscrambler.com). However, none of these will protect your code 100%.

Comment: My main concern lies in the fact that I have(?) to give access to my data to anyone that has embedded the HTML code. My second concern is how to serve the data. I have not any previous experience with kind of stuff though I am not fresh developer, to be honest.

A minor guide can be proved great, in that occasion.

Comment: Understood. You can control who has access based on the domain names where your widget will be run. It's nicely explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264938/how-to-get-url-of-embedding-page-for-a-javascript-widget

Comment: Although, it is fair explained on the above link, I feel like it is getting more complicated than initially thought.
If you ll come up with any thoughts or other links, feel free to share them.
 Cheers @xionutz2k  !

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the Data to FusionCharts that you are worried about, I would recommend the following.

1. Pass data to the chart via the data url method. (i.e. `setJSONUrl()` or `setXMLUrl()`)
2. Allow access to this data only from specific whitelisted referrers.

Say that in your page you have a chart. The code to render that chart would somewhat look like:

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "column2d",
    dataSource: "http://my-domain.com/datafolder/datafile.json",
    dataFormat: "jsonurl",
    renderAt: "my-chart-container-div"
}).render();
```

Notice that the data is being fetched via JSON (you may choose XML) format from a URL. (This FusionCharts documentation on [using JSON url for your data](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/JSONData.html) should help.) Now, you may restrict which source websites (domains) that can refer to this `datafile.json` URL. In PHP based server, it is very easy using `.htaccess` file. Setting up `.htaccess` is really easy and there are many online resources that can get you started. You can find more on this at http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

For example, you may have the `.htaccess` file within the `datafolder` directory that looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otherdomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} anotherdomain\.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The above rule will grant access to `otherdomain.com` and `anotherdomain.com` for linking to your files within `datafolder`.